# FileUtils.writeStringToFile() vs other File writing options

Tags: java, file-io

In my program I am taking around 40-50 files (anywhere from ~1 KB to 20 MB), editing their contents, and then rewriting them using `FileUtils.writeStringToFile()`. I was just wondering the performance difference (if any) for these amount/size of files between `writeStringToFile()` and other file writers, such as `BufferedWriter` or `FileWriter`.

Comment: Measuring is knowing.

Comment: Difference should be roughly 0 if you mean the Apache Commons `FileUtils` and you write the whole file in a single operation. There is simply nothing to buffer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is much easier and faster to use the `FileUtils` method than always write a new code block.

You could also write your own "writeStringToFile" method if you want to have more control.
But if the `FileUtils` method works fine for you, you should simply continue using this method.